# Is it possible to declare a function that takes an argument, but then call it with no argument?

Tags: python

Here is the scenario:

```
from scipy.special import lambertw
import numpy as np

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3 

def my_func(c_s):
   return a*b*np.exp(c_s*c**2)

print(my_func(c_s))
```

I want to print the result of my_func as a function of c_s (where we do not know c_s). This means I want the result of `print(my_func(c_s))` to come out as:

```
2*exp(9*c_s)
```

Even if I encapsulate things in mathematical function like so:

```
print(lambertw(my_func(c_s)))
```

I still want my result in terms of c_s but evaluate all other numbers. Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: Transforming a function in order to solve it in terms of a specified parameter (rather than simply evaluating it with given parameter values) is in the domain of a symbolic math package such as `sympy`.

Comment: Are you looking for a symbolic math package? Is `2*exp(9*c_s)` supposed to be a string? Or a function? In the last case I can help you some. Please clarify the question.

Comment: Ok, but how would you use SymPy to do that?

Comment: You can chain functions, make partial functions, etc. in python directly. You can also evaluate a function over multiple inputs quickly with something like numpy. But you need sympy or equivalent to do symbolic math.

Comment: @Woj. You would start by reading the manual. There is a bit of a learning curve, and SO is not a tutorial site.